# Permission denied at ssh.pl line 17 - $ssh->login($user, $password);

Tags: linux, perl, ssh

I am trying to ssh into a machine and run a command called `mounted` using a perl script.

I keep getting the error:

```
Permission denied at ssh.pl line 17
```

Line 17:

```
$ssh->login($user, $password);
```

Can anyone help me understand why?

Here's my complete script:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use warnings;
require Net::SSH::Perl;

#declare our login vars...

my $user = "root";
my $password = "";
my $server = "beccles";

#Setup our SSH Connection...
my $ssh = Net::SSH::Perl->new($server,port=>22,protocol=>2, debug => 1);

#Initiate out conneciton to the server...
$ssh->login($user, $password);

# Declare our variable for the request...
my $mounts;
my $name;

# Run our SSH Command and retrieve the output...
($mounts) = $ssh->cmd(`mounted`);
($name) = $ssh->cmd("uname -n");

# Print Output
chomp $name;
#print "\n$mounts\n";

exit 0;
```

And here's the output I get after I debug the ssh connection:

```
calver: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
calver: Net::SSH::Perl Version 1.37, protocol version 2.0.
calver: No compat match: OpenSSH_5.3
calver: Connection established.
calver: Sent key-exchange init (KEXINIT), wait response.
calver: Algorithms, c->s: 3des-cbc hmac-sha1 none
calver: Algorithms, s->c: 3des-cbc hmac-sha1 none
calver: Entering Diffie-Hellman Group 1 key exchange.
calver: Sent DH public key, waiting for reply.
calver: Received host key, type 'ssh-dss'.
calver: Host 'beccles' is known and matches the host key.
calver: Computing shared secret key.
calver: Verifying server signature.
calver: Waiting for NEWKEYS message.
calver: Send NEWKEYS.
calver: Enabling encryption/MAC/compression.
calver: Sending request for user-authentication service.
calver: Service accepted: ssh-userauth.
calver: Trying empty user-authentication request.
calver: Authentication methods that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-   
with-mic,keyboard-interactive.
calver: Next method to try is publickey.
calver: Publickey: testing agent key '/u/blh/.ssh/blh_git'
calver: Authentication methods that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-   
with-mic,keyboard-interactive.
calver: Next method to try is publickey.
Permission denied at ssh.pl line 17
```

Appreciate any help, if any more information need is needed, please ask me.

Thanks :)

Comment: I presume you have the real password in `$password`. You are able to ssh from the command line? Also, you don't want to put `mounted` in backticks.

Comment: I can ssh from command line, and the way it works is I don't need a password to ssh so I am not sure if I should assign anything in the password scalar that why i left it empty with "" . The reason why I have that in backticks is because mounted is a script that does not print out but is executable.

Comment: You are running this script as root user? I do think it is a security hole to allow root to ssh from one machine to another without a password. If you put `mounted` in backticks, it will run mounted on your local computer and try to sent its output to the remote computer as a command.

Comment: Well this is the way our security has been setup in the company. We have many scripts that are only executable if you are a root, also our user accounts do not have passwords either. Ahh i c, I can see your point in the backticks. So is there a way around the ssh->login issue?

Comment: try `$ssh->login()` (since you are running the script as root) or `$ssh->login($user)`

Comment: Try `protocol=>'2,1'` in your initialization of `$ssh`

Comment: getting this now followed by permission denied. Odd number of elements in hash assignment at /usr/local/share/perl5/Net/SSH/Perl.pm line 39.

Comment: Maybe you missed a comma in the parameters.

Comment: yes u a right, I did not put the , but either how. Still getting the permission denied. Do you reckon it might be due to the way the network/user accounts has been setup in the company.

Comment: Maybe have a look at this other question. If you don't use a password to log in I assume you're using key files. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3578192/how-to-use-netsshperl-with-public-keys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to have an official answer from the comment of [AKHolland](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1466640/akholland) and from the the answer of [Arthur Ulfeldt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/90801/arthur-ulfeldt) to [his own question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3578192/510599) :

Use keys and define manually your key file location :

```
@KEYFILE = ("/root/.ssh/id_rsa");
$ssh = Net::SSH::Perl->new($host, debug=>1, identity_files=>\@KEYFILE)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an old thread, but it came up while I was searching other items relating to Net::SSH::Perl.

This assumes that the password shown in the code is not an empty string, and is in fact a redacted but valid password.

I ran in to this, the problem was that I was assuming that I was using password authentication when logging into a remote host interactively. Actually, what I was using was the `keyboard-interactive` authentication, and `password` authentication was disabled on the sshd server.

I added `PasswordAuthentication yes` to my `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, restarted the sshd process, and all was good with Net::SSH::Perl.